# Azure Graph API Call get only application groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[I have azure AD with 3 groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dp9k.png)

I execute api call for retrieve it

1. Login : https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/oauth2/token
2. Get groups : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
3. Get users : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupID}/members

Thats OK, i receive 3 groups and users inside
But for now i need only groups that assigned to applications 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62hCH.png)

I cant find any methods in graph api for filter it . 
If somebody know how to do it , help please

Comment: Resolve problem use
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/${applicationId}/appRoleAssignments

Comment: If it is resolved, you could add it as an answer to help other communities easily to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve this problem in such way:

1. Get all groups as before
2. Get groups and users assigned to application graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/${applicationId}/appRoleAssignments

Response :

```js
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#appRoleAssignments",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "tV-E7eUeFkmIemkoWcUgTkrT54btaddPtiLX96wVx0g",
            "creationTimestamp": "2018-07-06T10:43:32.548348Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "Pasha Kostohrys",
            "principalId": "${userID}",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "azure-group-sync",
            "resourceId": "${applicationId}"
        },
        {
            "id": "ZRCxfjNVlUqrjp9Y3wuLJz6beU58dtNOvr41VsKwADo",
            "creationTimestamp": null,
            "principalDisplayName": "ops",
            "principalId": "${groupID}",
            "principalType": "Group",
            "resourceDisplayName": "azure-group-sync",
            "resourceId": "${applicationId}"
        }
    ] }
```

3. Just filter groups that are not in assignments list

Comment: I think you could just use beta/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments which lists all the apps the user has access to. But that doesn't filter on a particular group. I have been looking for something like this for a while. It has been rough since the documentation is always updating and MS is migrating away from other APIs. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

To get the groups assigned to an application (Service Principal)

Microsoft Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<servicePrincipal_id/appRoleAssignedTo
```

Microsoft Graph powershell:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId
```